# Application in Unity2D with Google Game Services and Prime31 IABilling crashes after adding Admob or Startapp *Unity Project

Tags: unity-game-engine, google-play, admob, banner

Application crashes with Admob or Startapp with the message: "unfortunately the application stopped working". I believe from what i read that it has something to do with Google Play Games Service Plugin. I have to mention that i also have Prime31 Store Kit and prime 31 IABilling.

The counsele does not show any errors when the game compiles. 
* i have installed the Admob plugin without google play games and it worked fine.

How can i fix this? Could it be because of the manifest? or different libraries?

Comment: are all the plugins prime31 or just some of them, prime31 GPGS overrides unity's main activity and for plugins to be compatible with it they have to follow prime31 guidelines for making the plugin, i also have the same problem i have all prime31 plugins and i tried to use facebook sdk and they are incompatible so i have to purchace prime31 social networking plugin to use facebook, maybe plugins are incompatible that you have

Comment: No, not all the Plugins are Prime31. Just IABilling for Android and the Storekit for iOS. The GPGS is from Google. Prime31 IABilling and Storekit + GPGS from Google work fine from what i can tell. But when i try to add a banner it stopped the application

Comment: Did you find any solution?